# Can we use svn2cl on launchpad buildbots?

Tags: compiling, packaging, launchpad, svn, recipe

I've done a build bot for doxbox and currently i'm merging a packaging bzr repo - but that repo has the changelog outdated - and i don't want to have to maintain it.

I've read dosbox autogenerates it's changelog with svn2cl on the svn local repo.
I'm asking if there is some way to do this in the launchpad recipe bellow.
However, note if you're not familiar with launchpad that the code mirrors that it uses don't use svn (everything is periodically imported into a bzr repo) and that recipes don't allow internet access.

https://code.launchpad.net/~i30817/+recipe/dosbox-patched

Answer (score 0):

Is the changelog really important in daily builds?

But no, you can't really do this. The package build happens from a source package, without any bzr history available.

Actually, it's possible that the recipe build calls `debian/rules clean`, and you could do something in there. I can't remember if it does or not.

Comment: Even if it was called on a repository, there is no bzr2cl command, so it wouldn't work.